# displays values of array in ForEach Swift UI

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, foreach, swiftui

I am using SwiftUI and I want to simply display array values in a Text form.

**Here is my code:**

```
    ForEach(0..<returnCont().count) {
       Text("\(returnCont()[$0]),")
    }
```

I also tried this:

```
    ForEach(returnCont().indices) {
        Text("\(return()[index]),")
    }
```

Where returnCont() is a function returning an array.

The array displays elements that are initialised, but when the array is empty and then appended through user inputs, it only displays values in the terminal, but not in the Text form on the View.

No error is displayed either, just empty text.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below-:

```
import SwiftUI


class Model:ObservableObject{
    var dataArray = ["1","2","3"]
    func returnCont() -> Int{
        return dataArray.count
    }
}
struct myView:View{
    @ObservedObject var model = Model()
    var body: some View{
        ForEach(0..<model.returnCont()) { index in
            Text("\(model.dataArray[index]),")
           }
    }
}
```

I don’t know how your model class looks like, so this is just a demo to give you correct idea.

Comment: Thank you. Does this work only with ObservableObject, or NSObjects too?

Comment: @mikey1091 If the model is only for reading data, yes you can use NSObjects as well, but if you want view updates to take place on changing your model, you need to have ObservableObject protocol implemented.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it did not work.. I did not get any errors so that was a good sign, but my array did not appear.

Comment: @mikey1091 please edit your post and show reproducible code.